# distance random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalue

In some physics problems it is sometimes useful to define a distance matrix for a system of particles with positions denoted by $x_1$, ..., $x_N$. Then the matrix would be given by
$$M_{ij}=f(x_i-x_j)+\alpha\delta_{ij}\sum_{k}_{k\ne i}f(x_i-x_k)$$
where $f$ is a function yet to be defined and $\alpha$ is a constant parameter, which can be specified for different models. For simplicity, let's define $f(x_i-x_j)=x_i-x_j$ and assume that all the positions are uniformly distributed on a straight line of finite length. Furthermore, setting $\alpha=0$. Then we simply have 
$$M_{ij}=x_i-x_j$$

I know that the matrix $M$ contains information about the position correlations of the $N$ particles. But what do the eigenvalues represent and what are the physical meaning for the eigenvectors?

Comment: IMHO, for an arbitrary function this expression doesn't mean anything. Pick f = 0 (perfectly valid under your definition) and then you get the zero matrix. What does that "mean" for your problem?

Comment: by asking this question I mean some nontrivial functions of physical significance, for instance $e^{-|x_i-x_j|/\xi}$. and for simplicity we can assume all the positions are uniformly distributed in a straight line of finite length.

Comment: There is no difference in physics between trivial and non-trivial functions. Neither is there a difference in physics between uniform distributions and any other distribution. Why don't you tell me where you saw this and what problem you have with the context? That way we save ourselves a lot of agony about me trying to guess what's really on your mind.

Comment: it appears in the study of localization problem in condensed matter system. you can refer to this paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321399004289 and http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.070601

Comment: I have no access to these papers. I can't help you. In any case... shouldn't the paper tell you what it's all about?

Comment: @CuriousOne I tried but kind of get stuck in the first paper. I can try to search more into the literature. thanks for your help.